# Can I install Ubuntu and Ubuntu-Mate at the same time?

Tags: dual-boot

Can I install "Ubuntu 15.10" and "Ubuntu-Mate 15.10" at the same time in my PC?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. 
if you are asking about dual booting it won't cause any problem and it's a simple procedure. if you are looking for installing mate in your current ubuntu machine use [mate ppa for ubuntu 15.10](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/wily-mate) or use there commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/wily-mate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-core
```

Comment: Thank you very much, actually I installed Ubuntu with MATE, and now I want to install the original Ubuntu (I think its default desktop is UNITY).  Or may be I don't need to install a complete new OS, can I install only the UNITY desktop?

Comment: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop use this command this will install unity desktop